# Question about the hfs-structure of the H-atom

Tags: quantum-spin

Considering the hyper-fine-structure configuration of the H-atom, why is its stable, low energy state (or the "flipped-back" state) the state when the spins of the electron and the proton point in the same direction, ie are parallel (and not antiparallel, as is sometimes stated in the literature)?